# Android Studio: EditText editable y desplegable

Tags: android, android-studio

¿Se puede hacer que un campo `EditText` sea a su vez desplegable?

Lo que necesito es un campo desplegable donde se pueda seleccionar un elemento (item) y si no existe el que se desea entonces se escribe.

Actualmente tengo esto en un layout

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/marco1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/cmpCodigoTienda"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="código tienda"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Pero únicamente permite introducir un texto. Lo que busco es algo que sea un `spinner`+`EditText`. No se si existe ya en Android Studio o habría que crearlo uno personalizado.

¿Como se podría hacer?

Comment: Hola creo que lo que estas buscando es AutoCompleteTextView podrias revisarlo :D

Comment: Hola, por favor considera agregar más detalles sobre el error que tienes, código de ejemplo y/o replicar tu error para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es el código con el que finalmente lo he podido hacer.
Gracias @Carlosgub por la ayuda.

```
    AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listaEmpresas);
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoRellenable);
    actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
    actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    ImageView btnFlechaAbajo = findViewById(R.id.btnFlechaAbajo);

    btnFlechaAbajo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
       actv.showDropDown();
      }
    });
```

En el layout he puesto un `AutoCompleteTextView` y a su lado una imagen de una flecha hacia abajo.
Al escribir en el campo va mostrando las opciones que existen en el Array que coincidan con la cadena escrita. Pero si se pulsa en la flecha despliega la lista completa del Array.